# How to get last items of a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, slice

I need the last 9 numbers of a list and I'm sure there is a way to do it with slicing, but I can't seem to get it.  I can get the first 9 like this:

```
num_list[0:9]
```

Comment: Related: [How to extract the last x elements from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8556076/5989200)

Answer (score 755, accepted):

You can use negative integers with the slicing operator for that. Here's an example using the python CLI interpreter:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> a[-9:]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

the important line is `a[-9:]`

Comment: Note that `-0` is `0`. So `a[-0:]` returns whole `a`, not the last zero elements `[]`. For guarding zero, you can use `a[-n:] if n > 0 else []`.

Answer (score 138):

a negative index will count from the end of the list, so:

```
num_list[-9:]
```

Answer (score 105):

## Slicing

Python slicing is an incredibly fast operation, and it's a handy way to quickly access parts of your data.

Slice notation to get the last nine elements from a list (or any other sequence that supports it, like a string) would look like this:

```
num_list[-9:]
```

When I see this, I read the part in the brackets as "9th from the end, to the end." (Actually, I abbreviate it mentally as "-9, on")

### Explanation:

The full notation is

```
sequence[start:stop:step]
```

But the colon is what tells Python you're giving it a slice and not a regular index. That's why the idiomatic way of copying lists in Python 2 is

```
list_copy = sequence[:]
```

And clearing them is with:

```
del my_list[:]
```

(Lists get `list.copy` and `list.clear` in Python 3.)

### Give your slices a descriptive name!

You may find it useful to separate forming the slice from passing it to the `list.__getitem__` method ([that's what the square brackets do](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)). Even if you're not new to it, it keeps your code more readable so that others that may have to read your code can more readily understand what you're doing.

However, you can't just assign some integers separated by colons to a variable. You need to use the slice object:

```
last_nine_slice = slice(-9, None)
```

The second argument, `None`, is required, so that the first argument is interpreted as the `start` argument [otherwise it would be the `stop` argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice).

You can then pass the slice object to your sequence:

```
>>> list(range(100))[last_nine_slice]
[91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

## `islice`

`islice` from the itertools module is another possibly performant way to get this. `islice` doesn't take negative arguments, so ideally your iterable has a `__reversed__` special method - which list *does* have - so you must first pass your list (or iterable with `__reversed__`) to `reversed`.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> islice(reversed(range(100)), 0, 9)
<itertools.islice object at 0xffeb87fc>
```

islice allows for lazy evaluation of the data pipeline, so to materialize the data, pass it to a constructor (like `list`):

```
>>> list(islice(reversed(range(100)), 0, 9))
[99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91]
```

Comment: Your mental abbreviation is very helpful

Answer (score 47):

The last 9 elements can be read from left to right using numlist[-9:], or from right to left using numlist[:-10:-1], as you want.

```
>>> a=range(17)
>>> print a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
>>> print a[-9:]
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
>>> print a[:-10:-1]
[16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8]
```

Answer (score 11):

Here are several options for getting the "tail" items of an iterable:

**Given**

```
n = 9
iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Desired Output

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

**Code**

We get the latter output using any of the following options:

```
from collections import deque
import itertools

import more_itertools


# A: Slicing
iterable[-n:]


# B: Implement an itertools recipe
def tail(n, iterable):
    """Return an iterator over the last *n* items of *iterable*.

        >>> t = tail(3, 'ABCDEFG')
        >>> list(t)
        ['E', 'F', 'G']

    """
    return iter(deque(iterable, maxlen=n))
list(tail(n, iterable))


# C: Use an implemented recipe, via more_itertools
list(more_itertools.tail(n, iterable))


# D: islice, via itertools
list(itertools.islice(iterable, len(iterable)-n, None))


# E: Negative islice, via more_itertools
list(more_itertools.islice_extended(iterable, -n, None))
```

---

**Details**

- A. Traditional Python [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-slice-notation) is inherent to the language.  This option works with [sequences](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesseq.html) such as strings, lists and tuples.  However, this kind of slicing does not work on [iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols), e.g. `iter(iterable)`.
- B. An [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).  It is generalized to work on any iterable and resolves the iterator issue in the last solution.  This recipe must be implemented manually as it is not officially included in the `itertools` module.
- C. Many recipes, including the latter tool (B), have been conveniently implemented in third party packages.  Installing and importing these these libraries obviates manual implementation.  One of these libraries is called `more_itertools` (install via `> pip install more-itertools`); see [`more_itertools.tail`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.tail).
- D. A member of the `itertools` library.  Note, `itertools.islice` [does not support negative slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).
- E. Another tool is implemented in `more_itertools` that generalizes `itertools.islice` to support negative slicing; see [`more_itertools.islice_extended`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.islice_extended).

*Which one do I use?*

*It depends*.  In most cases, slicing (option A, as mentioned in other answers) is most simple option as it built into the language and supports most iterable types.  For more general iterators, use any of the remaining options.  Note, options C and E require installing a third-party library, which some users may find useful.