# Access last two elements during list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a list where each element depends on the two previous elements eg. Fibonacci:

```
fibonacci = [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21]
```

I want to create such a list using a comprehension like so:

```
fibonacci = [0,1] + [previous_element+element_before_previous_element for _ in range(7)]
```

(7 here is just some arbitary value for how long the list should be excluding the starting 2 values.)

How do I access `previous_element` and `element_before_previous_element`, and use 0 and 1 as starting values?

Note: I know this is trivial with a for loop but I need to able to write this in one line.

Comment: The question seems a bit repetitive, have you checked the next two questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646644/how-to-get-last-items-of-a-list-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556076/python-how-to-extract-the-last-x-elements-from-a-list

Comment: @a0m0rajab both of those answers use a preexisting list, but I want to access elements of a list during its own comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[j := 0, k := 1] + [(k := j + (j := k)) for i in range(7)]
```

For future readers:
What's this? `:=` it's walrus operator that was introduced in Python 3.8 for new assignment everywhere in your code just like here. https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/

For start, I assign 0 and 1 to j and k respectively, and we do 2 task same time. create a list: `[0, 1]` and assign j and k values.

it's equivalent to:

```
j, k = 0, 1
lst = [j, k]
```

now, second part:
assume this without any walrus operator:

```
[(j + (k)) for i in range(7)]
```

It means a list of `j + k` for 7 times. But If you need Fibonacci, you must update j and k every times... update k to j (previous) value and assign new value to k...

| step | j | k |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |

see? this mean if you get new value, assign it to k and assign current value of k to j, but do second task first

```
[(k := j + (j := k)) for i in range(7)]
```

this snippet does that. it gets `j` (current value) `j +` and assigns `k` current value to `j` then assigns `j + k` to `k`.

all done!

output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
```

Comment: @Ch3steR Thank you very much... but I am not certain that if it is what OP want or not... but I add description and some document link for walrus operator soon :)

Comment: Sounds good, thanks @MoRe. Deleted my previous comment. Posting my approach here again `[(prev2:=prev1+prev2, prev1:=prev2-prev1)[0] for _ in range(10)]`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly after some changes to make it fit into one line!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to able to write this is one line.

A one-liner can be done with `functools.reduce`

```py
from functools import reduce

fibonacci = reduce(lambda acc, _: acc + [acc[-2] + acc[-1]], range(7), [0, 1])

print(fibonacci)
```

I can't speak to its efficiency, since it's creates a copy of the list each iteration.

> I want to create such a list using a comprehension

I know this solution doesn't do this... but just with a list comprehension is tricky because the list needs to exist in order to take the last and second-to-last items, but it doesn't exist until the list comprehension has been fully evaluated. I'm suspecting that it'll need a solution that uses some sort of "state" for this external to the list comprehension.

Answer (score -1):

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
last_two = my_list[-2:]
print(last_two)
```