# Looping over subset in Jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

Jinja allows me to do

```
{% for item in all_items %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

but I'd like to be able to only take the first *n* items; in Python that would be

```
for item in all_items[:n]:
```

Is there any elegant way to do this in Jinja, except

```
{% for item in all_items %}
    {% if loop.index <= n %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use normal python slice syntax.

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> t = jinja2.Template("{% for i in items[:3] %}{{ i }}\n{% endfor %}")
>>> items = range(10)
>>> print(t.render(items=items))
0
1
2
```

Comment: As often in life, we sometimes fail to see the most obvious. Thanks :)

Comment: @miku, how to get last 3 item?

Comment: @miku, no worries, I got it over here [-3:] http://stackoverflow.com/a/646654/1292050