# Jinja2: How to identify the var type before any loop

Tags: python, jinja2

With Jinja2, is there any way to identify the variable used in `PARSER` before doing the `for` loop?

```
 Context = """
   {% macro LopyLoop(PARSER) %}
      {% for items in PARSER -%}
         {{ items }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
      {%- endfor %}
   {% endmacro %}
 
   {% set Mainlist =  ['ABC','XYZ']  %}
 
   {{ LopyLoop(Mainlist) }}
   {{ LopyLoop(Mainlist[0]) }}
 
 )
  """
 Output = Template(Context)
 print Output.render()
```

The above is valid is valid when using `["ABC","XYZ"]` but is not when using a string `Mainlist[0]`

I can't find the a way to solve this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking around i found this link
[Looping over subset in Jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610393/looping-over-subset-in-jinja)

The answer is to 
  {{ LopyLoop(Mainlist[0:1]) }}