# How can I play a sound activated by a number of actions per time?

Tags: python

How can I call a function, for example Play a sound, if I do 3 blinks in a space of 2 seconds?

```
if blinking_ratio > 5.7:
    cv2.putText(frame, "BLINKING", (50, 150), font, 7, (255, 0, 0))
    winsound.PlaySound("campainha.wav.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

Here if I blink, the sound plays... I want to play, only if I blink 3 times in 2 secs for example...

Comment: You could make a list of timestamps for when "blink" was called. Then each time it is called you check if the previous 2 calls were not longer than 2 seconds ago.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646644/how-to-get-last-items-of-a-list-in-python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a `Time` class by using

```
class Time(datetime.tzinfo):
  def utcoffset(self, x):
    return datetime.timedelta(hours=-5) + self.dst(x)

  def dst(self, x):
    date = datetime.datetime(x.year, 3, 8)
    self.dston = date + datetime.timedelta(days=6-date.weekday())
    date = datetime.datetime(x.year, 11, 1)
    self.dstoff = date + datetime.timedelta(days=6-date.weekday())
    if self.dston <= x.replace(tzinfo=None) < self.dstoff:
      return datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
    else:
      return datetime.timedelta(0)

  def tzname(self, x):
    return 'Time'

def timeStamp():
  return datetime.datetime.now(tz=Time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

From this, you could do something like

```
while . . .:
  start = timeStamp()
  blinkOnce()
  end = timeStamp()
  if start - end < 2:
    pass
  else:
    break
```

Of course you would adjust the second code segment to whatever conditions you want to be met, but the end is just some pseudocode that you could edit accordingly.