# How to get latest 3 .jpeg files from the folder

Tags: python

I want to get latest 3 ".jpeg"  files from a folder using python
I tried like

```
import os
import glob


path = "path of the folder\\*.jpeg"
list_of_files = glob.iglob(path) 
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)
```

But I got only one file as output. How to get latest 3 files from a folder?

Comment: Use this with the sorted list of files: [How to get last items of a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646644/how-to-get-last-items-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: No as  latest file is giving only one file as output , not the list

Comment: you are doing max. so it will give you only one. do you want to sort in reverse order so you can get the first 3 or the regular sort so you can take the last 3?

Comment: Yes, because that's exactly what the answerss you already received do. Are you saying they don't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sort the list by date and pluck off the last three elements.

```py
import os
import glob


path = "path of the folder\\*.jpeg"
latest_files = sorted(glob.iglob(path), key=os.path.getctime))
print(latest_files[-3:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import os
import glob
    
    
files_path = os.path.join("C:\\Users\\User\\Pycharmprojects\\other\\", '*') 
list_of_files = sorted(glob.iglob(files_path), key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)
list_of_files=[i for i in list_of_files if i[-4:]=='jpeg']
latest_files = list_of_files[:3]
print(latest_files)
```

Comment: `files_path = os.path.join(folder, '*')
files = sorted(
    glob.iglob(files_path), key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True) `

Comment: yup sorry. not thinking straight tonight. upvoted your sort response.

Comment: I added your option though as it sorts better the object by time