# Extract some portion of path

Tags: python

I have a long file path and I need to extract last 3 subfolders. For example, if my path is:

`a\b\c\d\e\f\g`

then I need only last 3 folders:

`e\f\g`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Step 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167154/how-to-split-a-dos-path-into-its-components-in-python; Step 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646644/how-to-get-last-items-of-a-list-in-python

Comment: ```'\\'.join(path_name.split("\\")[-3:])```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the terms in `\` and join it:

```
'\\'.join(path_name.split("\\")[-3:]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pathlib.PurePath.parts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts) like this:

```
import pathlib

p = pathlib.PureWindowsPath(r'a\b\c\d\e\f\g')
parts = p.parts[-3:]
# > ('e', 'f', 'g')
p3 = pathlib.PureWindowsPath(*parts)
print(p3)  # -> e\f\g
```

(I'm using Linux so I specified `PureWindowsPath`.)

Answer (score 2):

The best practice to deal with paths is to use `os` and it's seperator `os.sep` to split the path into pieces. Use `os.sep` instead of '\' or '/', as this makes it system independent.

```
import os

path = r'a\b\c\d\e\f\g'
path = os.path.normpath(path)
path_list = path.split(os.sep)
print(os.sep.join(path_list[-3:]))
```

It prints:

```
e\f\g
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with maxsplit of 3 :

```
a = r'a\b\c\d\e\f\g'
print('\\'.join(a.rsplit('\\', 3)[1:]))
```

output:

```
e\f\g
```